# tf AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'transformations'

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using roscopter package to get the imu data from my quadcopter.

It worked well but I got error when running it today.

```
rosrun roscopter imu_transform_publish.py

[ERROR] [WallTime: 1401208503.130663] bad callback: <function imu_callback at 0x18c9578>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 682, in _invoke_callback
cb(msg)
File "/home/aqua/ros_catkin/src/roscopter/scripts/imu_transform_publish.py", line 75, in imu_callback
q = tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(roll,pitch,yaw)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'transformations'
```

`import tf`

`q = tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(roll,pitch,yaw)`

According to the tf tutorial, `tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(roll,pitch,yaw)` should be correct, so I'm confused where the problem is.

also for the tf module, it locates in my catkin workspace:

```
Python 2.7.4 (default, Sep 26 2013, 03:20:26) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tf
>>> print tf
<module 'tf' from '/home/aqua/ros_catkin/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf/__init__.pyc'>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/170261/tf-attributeerror:-%27module%27-object-has-no-attribute-%27transformations%27/) by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on ROS Answers with karma: 279 on 2014-05-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jian1994](https://answers.ros.org/users/49742/jian1994/) on 2019-11-25**:
Hi, i am new to ros and just met the same problem. Just download a new tf-file from github as you did. But what should i do afterwards? Would you please explain more about integrating this file into catkin_ws? I use catkin_make rather than rosbuild

**Comment by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on 2019-11-25**:
@Jian1994 just put it into your catkin workspace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I cannot reproduce this problem in source:

```
In [1]: import tf
In [2]: tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(1,2,3)
Out[2]: array([-0.71828702,  0.31062245,  0.44443511,  0.43595284])
In [3]: print(tf)
<module 'tf' from '/home/tfoote/work/geometry_experimental/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf/__init__.pyc'>
```

Or from debian packages:

```
In [1]: import tf
In [2]: tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(1,2,3)
Out[2]: array([-0.71828702,  0.31062245,  0.44443511,  0.43595284])
In [3]: print(tf)
<module 'tf' from '/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf/__init__.pyc'>
```

I'd suggest that you make sure that your environment is clean and the referenced init script is pointing to a valid source directory.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on 2014-05-27**:
I still failed...
Could you help check what is inside folder `home/tfoote/work/geometry_experimental/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf`? beside **init**.py  **init**.pyc  I found the `msg` and `srv` folders but both are empty.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-05-27**:
That suggests that you have not fully built the package. The generated messages are required and your tf library is probably missing the compiled so files too making the import malfunction.  Although you're using the python pieces, some of them depend on compiled and generated code from the build step.

**Comment by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on 2014-05-27**:
thanks. I downloaded https://github.com/ros/geometry/tree/hydro-devel/tf to my catkinWorkspace and build it, it works.